# Who know how apply django-smart-selects?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I read all the relation answer with [django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects), and everybody give us the link but it is not clear enough to apply it.

I have the follow models:

```
class Segment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Emplead(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    segment = models.ForeignKey(Segment)

class Grup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
emplead = models.ForeignKey(Emplead)
```

I don't know if i must use **GroupedForeignKey** or **ChainedForeignKey** and how will be the form?

Comment: What functionality do you want?

Comment: When i selected one Segment, the Emplead should show only the fields that belong to the selected segment, and when I selected the Emplead, Grup must show the fields that belong to the selected Emplead